# List of DocuSign Api Base Urls for EU account

Tags: docusignapi, production, e-signature

As it stands in DocuSign documentation:

> Update API calls to use the account's base URI You must update your integration to use your account’s base URI for API calls, instead of demo.docusign.net. You can use the UserInfo Authentication Service endpoint to get the base URI for an account.
>
> Note: Accounts move between base URIs infrequently, so the data can be cached for a day or more.

[Hier a list of the DocuSign servers can been found.](https://www.docusign.com/trust/compliance/public-certificates)

In the "**Go-live**" documentation stands that:

> ...
>
> Production    https://{server}.docusign.net/...
>
> Note: {server} is the data center location of your production account (for example, NA1, NA2, or EU). You can obtain your production data center location from:
>
> ...

The admin account is located in EU. Does this mean that the production server will always be EU or it will also call the NA1, NA2 etc.?

From the following list will every server be part of the infrequent change?

- https://na1.docusign.net
- https://na2.docusign.net
- https://na3.docusign.net
- https://na4.docusign.net
- https://eu.docusign.net
- https://au.docusign.net
- https://ca.docusign.net

Will be more servers in the future (EU1, EU2 etc.)?

**Clarification:**
I want to have a firewall rule to my server and I want to be 100% sure that every server will be accessible. What it is not clear to me, is the "Accounts move between base URIs infrequently" note. Does this apply to NA only (because only NA has more than one server)?

Answer (score 1):

If you make the [getUserInfo()](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/reference/user-info/) call you will get the list of accounts and for each one - its baseURI that will tell you what it is.

There may be more in the future, yes, but there's no way to get that information at present time.

Comment: My application is using getUserInfo(), this is not a problem. The reason I am asking is because I want to have a firewall rule to my server and I want to be 100% sure that every server will be accessible. What it is not clear to me, is the "Accounts move between base URIs infrequently" note. Does this apply to NA only (because only NA has more than one server)?

Comment: This note may have to be rewritten to clarify, but normally accounts do not move ever unless the customer is asking to do so (for example as a result of a merger or relocation of company). However, IP addresses (in case your firewall needs these too) can change at any time.